# Turn a CSS class inside function into jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css

I have this css class toggling in jQuery inside a function (credits to @Laurence for the code):

```
function rocksType_shift(direction) {
    $('#rocksType_DBitems_container .before').removeClass('before')[direction]().addClass('before');
          $('#rocksType_DBitems_container .current').removeClass('current')[direction]().addClass('current');
          $('#rocksType_DBitems_container .after').removeClass('after')[direction]().addClass('after');
}
```

Entire context - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNxeY/).

The classes have this configuration:

```
/* CSS styling for the 1st visible item (before) */
.before {
  background-color: Aquamarine;
  -webkit-border-radius: 70px 24px 24px 24px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 70px 24px 24px 24px;       
    border-radius: 70px 24px 24px 24px;
}

/* CSS styling for the 2nd visible item (current) */
.current {
  background-color: Aqua;
  border: 4px solid #000000; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 24px 24px 24px 24px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 24px 24px 24px 24px; 
    border-radius: 24px 24px 24px 24px;
}

/* CSS styling for the 3rd visible item (after) */
.after {
  background-color: Aquamarine;
  -webkit-border-radius: 24px 24px 24px 70px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 24px 24px 24px 70px; 
    border-radius: 24px 24px 24px 70px;
```

Question: I want to use animate(), so I can animate the border-radius. Can this be done?

Pedro

Comment: I think you need to have a look at jQuery css hooks to handle browser name prefixed properties like -moz-border-radius.
You could still try to animate the border-radius property, but all browsers that are not fully CSS3 compatible will fail.
What do you want to animate exactly ? Depending on what you want to do, it can be done using CSS3 transitions and/or animations.

Comment: You can using step option of animate but take into consideration Virus721's comment

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you want it to be with animate(), but since you already use CSS3, why don't you just do it by adding transition to `.rocksType_DBitem` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/vNxeY/1/

Comment: Correct, it's really better to use css3

Comment: My problem is with IE8 - it doesn't work... and I'm getting to the conclusion that it will never work.